# Access django cms Page cache

Tags: django-cms

I've got a page extension which can apply a colour to a page. This is accessed via a template tag which checks for an attribute of each page, and at the moment this is just running a `Page.objects.filter()` call which is obviously hammering the database because this is called for every nav_node in a menu.

Does the `Page` model have a cache I can run the `reverse_id` filter on? My extension object gets cached, but when trying to apply this filter to a menu item I need to try to establish if the `nav_node` is a `Page` as you see below so I have to go straight to the objects (or does that call the cache first?).

```
@register.filter(name='colour')
def colour(nav_node):
    """
    Filter receives a CMS menu NavigationNode. We cannot assume this is a Page.

    :param nav_node: a node from the cms menu
    :type nav_node: menus.base.NavigationNode
    :return: colour associated with the Node or None
    :rtype: str
    """
    pages = Page.objects.filter(reverse_id=nav_node.attr['reverse_id'])[0:2]
    page = next((x for x in pages if hasattr(x, 'pagecolourextension')), None)

    if page is None:
        colour = ''
    else:
        colour = page.pagecolourextension.page_colour

    return colour
```

I can't see anything on the `Page` model leading to a page cache, but on the manager there are plenty of calls to invalidate the page cache. How can you run a filter on the cached pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the best way to go about this was to create my own cache key for CMS Pages which I can use to access my page extensions, so I've moved the logic which queries the db;

```
pages = Page.objects.filter(reverse_id=nav_node.attr['reverse_id'])[0:2]
page = next((x for x in pages if hasattr(x, 'pagecolourextension')), None)
```

To put this into a `if cache.get(key):` type function so I have pages with a `reverse_id` accessible via my cache methods. This is great because it should enable me to cache page's and then for any of my page extensions call the cache and equally trigger signals based on changed fields.